# display drives with lsblk -o name -lpn , extract string containing "sd"

Tags: linux, centos, extract

So I've looked all over the place for what to do here and just find "from file". I am looking to extract from a command output.

Task: display the absolute path names of disks beginning with the sd.

Current progress: displaying absolute path name of disks

```
[host /]$ lsblk -o name -lpn
/dev/sda
/dev/sda1
/dev/mapper/centos-root
/dev/sda2
/dev/md127
....
```

Desired output

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
....
```

I've played around with cut, print, awk and sed.

Got syntax errors or no output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**grep**

```
lsblk -o name -lpn | grep "/dev/sd"
```

**awk**

```
lsblk -o name -lpn | awk '/dev\/sd/{print}'
```

**sed**

```
lsblk -o name -lpn | sed -n '/\/dev\/sd/p'
```

Output:

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
```

Answer (score 1):

lsblk accepts arguments, so you can in many cases just as easily say

```
  lsblk -no name -lp /dev/sd?
```

The ? is just wildcard match of a single character, so sda, sdb, ...

There is a potential pitfall. If you have more than 26 disks or you are working on a system that uses those unique disk identifiers. In which case you need to change the wildcard to an asterisk and filter out only the unique results,

```
  lsblk -no name -lp /dev/sd* | sort -u
```

Output (for either command):

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda3
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `sed`:

`lsblk -o name -lpn |sed -n '/\/sd/p'`